# How is this situation not a checkmate?

Tags: checkmate

According to the chess app I am using, this is not a checkmate against black:

```
[FEN "1rk4r/1p6/3p3q/Q1pPbRnP/p1P3B1/P6P/1P4R1/7K w - - 0 1"]

1. Rf7+
```

How is it not? I think the black king is checkmated by the queen and the white-squared bishop.

Comment: Black can block the g4-bishop's check with ...Ne6 or ...Qe6.

Comment: I don't really think this is a legitimate question for this site.  Just plug the situation into Lichess or any other online chess engine.  Or just manually go through black's pieces to see if any can stop the check.

Comment: Rf5-f8 would have been checkmate.

Comment: @Apollys why is this not a legitimate question?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is not checkmate because Black can interpose a piece to block the check from the bishop: move knight or queen to e6.

It's still only a miniscule delay for the inevitable.

```
[FEN "1rk4r/1p6/3p3q/Q1pPbRnP/p1P3B1/P6P/1P4R1/7K w - - 0 1"]

1.Rf7+ Ne6
(1...Qe6 2.Qc7#)
2.Qc7# 1-0
```

Comment: @Aqqqq, just an added note: Itub's answer is 100% correct, but do not be distracted by the move Ne6. Qc7 is then mate in one regardless of black's next move.

Comment: @PhishMaster: That is _also_ the case following ...Qe6, not just for ...Ne6.

Comment: @Sean, I realized that, but since Ne6 pseudo defends c7, I only mentioned that one possibility.